# Identify a Woocommerce page by Wordpress conditional tags

Tags: conditional-tags, woocommerce-offtopic

we have a website running on WPMU, and the main site is using Woo-commerce and the sub sites doesn't use that.
I use conditional statement in my meta title with following code:

```
<title>
<?php if( is_product_category( 'cds' ) ) { ?>
CD
<?php } elseif ( is_product_category( 'dvds' ) ) {?>
DVD
<?php } else {?>
<?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

but the thing is the sub sites, can not read this code, because the Woocommerce functions are undefined in those.
I almost sure that there is no way to identify a Woocommerce product page by WP core conditional tags, Do you guys have any idea how can i identify them?

Comment: Wrap your code in `is_main_site()`, or better yet, `function_exists( 'is_product_category' )`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Works fine, Post it as an answer and i can mark it then.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite you code as

```
        <title>
        <?php if (!function_exists( 'is_product_category' )) {
        if( is_product_category( 'cds' ) ) { ?>
        CD
        <?php } elseif ( is_product_category( 'dvds' ) ) {?>
        DVD
        <?php }
        }else { wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); } ?>
```